# How to not show null values in PHP

Tags: php, sql

:) Can you help me not show null values? Here's my code:
eeeeeeee

```
require 'databasename.php';
if (isset($_GET['id'])) { 
require 'databasename.php';
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['id']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `example` WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<div id='moveresults'>";

echo "<div id='as'>";
echo $data['As'];
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='so'>";
    echo $data['SO'];
echo "</div>";


echo "<div id='custom'>";
    if($data['Custom'] != '' || $data['Custom'] != NULL) {
    echo $data['Custom'];   
    }
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='local'>";
    if($data['Address'] != '' || $data['Address'] != NULL) {
    echo $data['Address'];  
    }
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='headof'>";
    if($data['Head'] != '' || $data['Head'] != NULL) {
    echo $data['Head']; 
    }
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='credl'>";
    if($data['Credit'] != '' || $data['Credit'] != NULL) {
    echo $data['Credit'];   
    }
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='currenta'>";
    echo $data['Current'];
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='totalex'>";
    echo $data['Exposure'];
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='termspay'>";
    if($data['Payment'] != '' || $data['Payment'] != NULL) {
    echo $data['Payment'];  
    }
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='overdue'>";
    echo $data['Overdue'];
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='pdc'>";
    echo $data['PDC'];
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='pending'>";
    echo $data['Pending'];
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='overallex'>";
    echo $data['Overall'];
echo "</div>";

echo "</div>";

}

?>
```

I tried the if ! which I saw in another post but I'm thinking it's either I typed wrong format or there's another way around. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to **populate**  your whole `div` in the `if` statement like this:

```
if($data['Custom'] != '' || $data['Custom'] != NULL) {
  echo "<div id='overdue'>";
     echo $data['Custom'];
  echo "</div>";   
}
```

And of course you need to **apply** this to all your `divs`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `is_null()`

```
if(!is_null($data['Custom']))
```

But null, empty, blank etc... are different, so sometimes you will need to check accordingly.

To make life easier, you can write a helper method

```
function isNullOrEmpty($value)
{
   return is_null($value) || empty($value) || strlen(trim($value)) === 0;
}
```

Then use it

```
if(!isNullOrEmpty($data['Custom']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep that syntax, just replace the OR condition (||) with an AND (&&), otherwise both empty string and NULL will be shown (since their value will always differ from one among the two above).

```
if($data['Custom'] != '' && $data['Custom'] != NULL) {
    // do something
}
```

However, you should avoid entirely avoid that and rewrite your IF condition in the following way (assuming you want to NOT SHOW either null and/or empty string):

```
if (array_key_exists("Custom", $data) && !empty($data["Custom"])) {
   // do something
}
```

If you want to show empty string, but not NULL values, try the following one instead:

```
if (array_key_exists("Custom", $data) && !is_null($data["Custom"])) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always check to make sure that your variables are set first, and then use the && operator to make sure it matches all requirements, not just some ( the || or opperator ).

```
if(isset($data['Head']) && $data['Head'] != '' && $data['Head'] != NULL) ...
```